# Azure Storage List Blobs using AAD Authentication - Audience validation failed

Tags: azure, rest, authentication, azure-blob-storage

Using Postman, get a Bearer token that is successful for listing storage accounts and resource groups. In that same collection, trying to list Blobs in a container and getting "Audience validation failed. Audience did not match". Any help to diagnose this error will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What was the audience for which you got the bearer token? I believe for listing blobs you would need to get a token for either `https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net` or `https://storage.azure.com/`.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you get Azure AD access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Azure AD access token to access Azure blob rest API, we need to assign Azure RABC Role (**Storage Blob Data Owner**, **Storage Blob Data Contributor** or **Storage Blob Data Reader**) to service principal or AD user. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

For example (I use the service principal )
1. create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role for the sp.

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# it will assign Storage Blob Data Reader to the sp at storage accountlevel
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "mysample" --role Storage Blob Data Reader --scopes <the resource id of storage account>
```

[image]

2. Get AD access token

```
POST /<your sp tenant id>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type =client_credentials
&client_id=<your sp appId>
&client_secret=<your sp password>k
&resource=https://storage.azure.com/
```

3. List blobs

```
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list

x-ms-version: 2017-11-09
Authorization: Bearer <access token>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I copied the Postman collection from my work with Logic Apps and neglected to change the resource to https://storage.azure.com/. Once I fixed that, all works great.